# Interpreting the isometries of a tetrahedron

Tags: symmetry, isometry, platonic-solids

A tetrahedron has $12$ rotational symmetries and $24$ isometries in total. This means that the group of isometries is isomorphic to $S_4.$

> If we denote the vertices of a tetrahedron as $1$, $2$, $3$, and $4,$ then what will be the interpretation of the transformation that permutes the vertices as follows:
> $$
> 1 \to 2 \to 3 \to 4 \to 1, 
> $$
> as a cycle of length $4?$

I mean, in terms of rotations and reflections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A $4-$cycle corresponds to the compose of a rotation and a symmetry. Indeed, you can write
$$(1 \text{ } 2 \text{ } 3 \text{ } 4)= (1 \text{ } 2 \text{ } 3)(3 \text{ } 4) $$

and it is easy to see that a $3-$cycle is a rotation and a transposition is a planar symmetry.

Comment: So, only a composition? It's not a reflection or a rotation about a tricky axis?

Comment: I guess you cannot reduce it to a single reflection. But you can also represent $S_4$ as the group of positive isometries of the cube (by its action on the four main diagonal of the cube), and with this representation, all the elements of $S_4$ correspond to a single rotation.

Comment: You can see this for the tetrahedron : https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Full_tetrahedral_group_is_isomorphic_to_S4

Comment: @user35603 It may be analogous to [glide reflections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glide_reflection) in 2D. They're the composition of a translation and reflection, but those individual symmetries may or may not be symmetries of the pattern. I bring this up because your permutation is an odd permutation, so it can't possibly be the result of rotations only, nor is it a single reflection